# android Date + 14 and custom days

Tags: java, android, date

I have 4 Textview's (named date0, date1, date2 and date3) and 1 editText (name datex), I need code that will show me today date in date0 (dd,mmm,yyyy) , tomorrow in date1, today + 14days in date2.
For date3 I need code to put custom date from editext (named- datex), when click on datex, enter value 1,2 or any number(10 for example), and then show date in date3=today+10.
Thanks

(I could not get it from tutorials..., I have errors)

I do not have code.

It do not need to be saved, only to show dates. UTC date would be better if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

## Today

Get the current date.

Specify a time zone (`ZoneId`) : for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Either specify custom formatting pattern (search Stack Overflow to learn more), or better, let *java.time* automatically localize. Specify a locale to determine the human language and cultural norms used for localization.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String outputToday = today.format( f ) ;
```

## Tomorrow

Add a day to get tomorrow.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Generate text in the same manner as seen above.

```
String outputTomorrow = tomorrow.format( f ) ;
```

### In two weeks

And add two weeks for future date.

```
LocalDate twoWeeksAhead = today.plusWeeks( 2 ) ;
```

Generate string as seen above.

All of this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. So search to learn more.

See the [code above run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jd77Pf).

> outputToday: 7 nov. 2019
>
> outputTomorrow: 8 nov. 2019
>
> outputTwoWeeks: 21 nov. 2019

[image: screenshot of IdeOne.com in action]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: @Namma I added a link to show this code running live at IdeOne.com: https://ideone.com/jd77Pf

Comment: Did you study all those mentions of Android at the end of my Answer?

Comment: @Namma Added screenshot showing IdeOne in action. The rest is up to you.

Comment: This answer goes above and beyond!